# Reshape/pad Numpy array - Python

Tags: python, numpy

I have a multiple numpy arrays like so:

```
[1, 5, 0, 0]
[2, 1, 3, 1]
[1, 3, 4, 1]
```

All my arrays have different values and shapes.

I want to write a function that will pad all my arrays to the same shape.

Currently, I am doing something like this (inside a for loop):

```
width = int(7000 - size[0])
height = int(7000 - size[1])
data = np.pad(data, (width, height), 'constant', constant_values=(0,0))
```

Where data is the array being edited, and 7000x7000 is my largest array.

This is giving me a MemoryError.

Comment: Get a bigger computer

Comment: Obviously this is a big waste of memory. Why do you want this? E.g. if you are stream-processing, you could use a generator.

Answer (score 0):

i tried my own code with this:

```
import numpy


def arrays(arr):
     return numpy.array(arr[::-1], float)


arr = input().strip().split(' ')
result = arrays(arr)
print(result)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).